# List of events possible in OpenAI Gym/Universe

Tags: openai-gym

I am using openai universe, I want the agent to click in keys like "a" "enter" etc. and click the mouse in a (x,y) position.

Any documentation will be awesome.

**UPDATE**
I found this link where list of KeyEvents are defined : 
https://github.com/openai/universe/blob/a7944e65446a5484e5011f048558f312e907da61/universe/vncdriver/constants.py#L85-L170

For letters just pass it : ('KeyEvent', "A", True)

For Mouse (Found in a comment somewhere in the universe code): ("PointerEvent", x, y, buttonmask)

[image]